# Unable to replace a particular object in a list?

Tags: c#, variable-assignment

```
SelectedListObjA.Where(x => x.FieldA == "ABC").FirstOrDefault() = ObjA;

SelectedListObjA = new List<ObjType>();
ObjType ObjA = new ObjType();
```

Can anyone explain to me why the above statement is wrong. It's throwing `The Left hand side of an assignment must be a variable...`

Comment: I thought `FirstOrDefault()` will return in an object?

Comment: Basically I will retrieve an obj where `FieldA == 'ABC'` and the first occurance will be replaced by `ObjA`. `ObjA.FieldA` will be for instance 'CDE'....Basically it's a different object

Comment: `ObjA = SelectedListObjA.Where(x => x.FieldA == "ABC").FirstOrDefault() `

Comment: Correct me if im wrong but your statement is to retrieve the object only while my objective is to replace the object

Comment: When you will assign the `object` it will be replaced by the new one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you get as result from `FirstOrDefault` is the first element in source. So you get an object. But assignment can be performed only on [variable, property or indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5s08de8.aspx). If you want to replace object you can use something like this:

```
var tmp = SelectedListObjA.Where(x => x.FieldA == "ABC").FirstOrDefault();
if (tmp != null) { // If tmp is reference type. Would be better to use default()
    var index = SelectedListObjA.IndexOf(tmp);
    SelectedListObjA[index] = ObjA;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't do that.

1. FirstOrDefault can return null. What would you suppose to happen. Shall the value be added to the list?
2. If FirstOrDefault will return an object, it will only be the reference to the object in a new variable. An assignment to that variable will not change the list, but only the reference the variable is pointing to. The List will stay unchanged.

If you want to replace an item in the list, you will need to find the index of that item and replace the object at that index with your new one.

```
var objectToReplace = SelectedListObjA.Where(x => x.FieldA == "ABC").FirstOrDefault();
if (objectToReplace != null)
{
    SelectedListObjA[SelectedListObjA.IndexOf(objectToRelplace)] = ObjA;
}
else
{
    SelectedListObjA.Add(ObjA);
}
```

Cheers

Thomas